# ¿Mejorar el formato de un select, a partir de una consulta con el ORM de Django 2.1.15 utilizando values_list?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Resultado deseado:

[image: Resultado esperado]

Resultado obtenido a partir de la siguiente consulta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
queryset= User.objects.values_list('first_name','last_name')
```

Si utilizo `flat=True` el formato se muestra correcto, de la siguiente manera:

```
queryset= User.objects.values_list('first_name', flat=True)
```

Sin embargo `flat=True` solo me permite especificar un parámetro es decir solo `first_name` de acuerdo al siguiente form

Form

```
tripulacion     =forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={
        'class':"form-control",

        }),
        required=True,
        error_messages={
        'required':'Selecciona el proovedor'
        },
        queryset= User.objects.values_list('first_name', flat=True)
        )
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Adjunta tus forms, de esta manera sera mas fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Agregue  form @JulioCesar

Comment: intenta con `from itertools import chain chain(objects.values_list('first_name','last_name'))` o con el metodo [union()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#union)

Comment: @NoelL acabo de publicar mi respuesta, échale un vistaso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El campo [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField), recibe una serie de argumentos, entre ellos `queryset`, dicho argumento debe recibir **un QuerySet de objetos de modelo**, no una cadena, tupla, lista, o lo que sea, debe ser instancias de un modelo si o si.

Y si intentas hacer un *submit* en tu formulario, no te dejara, ya que recibe un QuerySet no valido, dándote un error algo así:

> Escoja una opción válida. Esa opción no está entre las disponibles.

Entonces hay 2 formas de conseguir el resultado que quieres:

1. **Extendiendo el modelo `User` de Django:**

   El campo [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) llama al método `__str__` del modelo para generar representaciones en cadena de los objetos para usar en las opciones del campo. Entonces una opción es sobrescribir el método `__str__` del modelo `User`:

   ```
   def __str__(self):
       return self.get_full_name()
   ```

   Lo cual no recomiendo, ya que no vale la pena (es mucho relajo).
2. **Personalizar nuestro propio [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField):**

   Proporcionamos una representación del objeto personalizada, sobrescribiendo el método `label_from_instance`:

   ```
   class MyModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):

       def label_from_instance(self, obj):
           return obj.get_full_name()
   ```

   Y lo usamos:

   ```
   class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
      tripulacion = MyModelChoiceField(
          widget = forms.Select(attrs={'class':"form-control"}),
          error_messages={'required':'Selecciona el proovedor'},
          queryset= User.objects.all()
      )
   ```

   Esta opción es mucho mejor, ya que no es tan complicada.

Espero haberte ayudado.